# indexing for distinct to use covered query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, distinct-values

I'm not able to optimize a distinct query using indexes.

My collection look like this :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("592ed92296232608d00358bd"),
        "measurement" : ObjectId("592ed92196232608d0034c23"),
        "loc" : {
                "coordinates" : [
                        2.65939299848366,
                        50.4380671935187
                ],
                "type" : "Point"
        },
        "elements" : [
                ObjectId("592ed92196232608d0034c24"),
                ObjectId("592ed92196232608d0034c26"),
                ObjectId("592ed92196232608d0034c28")
        ]
}
```

I'm trying to execute a query like

```
db.mycol.distinct('elements', {  
   $and:[  
      measurement:{  
         $in:[  
            ObjectId("592ed92196232608d0034c23"),
            ObjectId("592ed92196232608d0034c24")
         ]
      },
      {  
         loc:{  
            $geoWithin:{  
               $geometry:{  
                  type:'Polygon',
                  coordinates:[[  
                    [  
                       2.0214843750000004,
                       50.25071752130677
                    ],
                    [  
                       2.0214843750000004,
                       50.65294336725709
                    ],
                    [  
                       3.0487060546875004,
                       50.65294336725709
                    ],
                    [  
                       3.0487060546875004,
                       50.25071752130677
                    ],
                    [  
                       2.0214843750000004,
                       50.25071752130677
                    ]
                 ]]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
})
```

And I have this index :

```
{
  measurement: 1,
  loc: '2dsphere',
  elements: 1
}
```

The query plan (`db.mycol.explain().distinct(...)`) shows an IXSCAN, but the query is taking ages. I added the index hoping that it could use a [Mongo covered query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query). The doc states that

> - all the fields in the query are part of an index,
> - and all the fields returned in the results are in the same index.

So I guessed I needed an index including `elements`. But according to the query execution time, it's not using it.

**What is the best way to index a collection for such a query ?**

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to create more than one `2dsphere` index on a collection. it is in fact not supported at all for operations like aggregation `$geoNear` and other `$near` based queries. You should pick your most used combination and stick to that.

Comment: Gonna try to let just 1 index and come back to tell you the result

Comment: Edited. I left only the 2 indexes containing "elements" (not sure where to put it, at the end or at the start, this is not documented). This results in a COLSCAN this time

Comment: Ha. Running query multiple times turn it into a IXSCAN, using the index with elements at the end. But I suspect this is just for "query" time, and not for "select" time (covered query). Because the query take ages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covered queries don't work with arrays.

From the same page referred in the question:

> Restrictions on Indexed Fields
>
> An index cannot cover a query if:
>
> - any of the indexed fields in any of the documents in the collection includes an array. If an indexed field is an array, the index becomes a multi-key index and cannot support a covered query.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Furthermore, What should be done to take best advantage of indexing system, and mongo engine, when trying to handle such a query ?

Comment: That's a bit more complex. Could you add result of `db.mycol.explain("allPlansExecution").distinct('elements', {....})` to the question (it might take some time, and the output is gonna be quite long)?